# centos 7 - can ping http & https websites but not able to browse http sites in any browser

Tags: http, centos7, ping

I messed up something in my centos 7 system. In terminal, i can ping http & https websites. But on any browser am not able to browse http sites.
Eg: I can ping yopmail.com
But in chrome, mozilla, firefox am not able to browse yopmail.com

Basically no webpages will open in any browser if its http.
But i can browse all https webpages. Unfortunately yopmail does not have https.

A week back i tried to set up an ipsec vpn. Didn't go well.
Am assuming i messed something up in the process. unfortunately i dont recall what all i tried out on that day.

Please give back any commands that will help you find the problem.

Any help is appreciated & Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So i figured it out.
But went thorough many stuffs to confirm
I reset my IP tables:

```
1036  iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
1037  iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
1038  iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
1039  iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
1040  iptables -F
```

Just to be sure.

Checked for all active services on the :

> ip a
>
> nmap -sT

But all of 'em had the http enabled. So problem was not that anyways (coz wget was working for http)

Then for firefox i had to check the proxy settings, it was enabled. That fixed issue in firefox. But chrome still had the issue.
In chrome the proxy settings was opening to CentOs Network setting panel, there also, in "Network Proxy setting" section, the proxy was set to manual. Changing that to Auto, fixed my 3 day long issue. Never checked the proxy section in particular.

Feels stupid after the silly fix, even tried reinstalling chrome 2 times.